# Exchange 2010 strange behaviour on search UID SEARCH CHARSET US-ASCII FROM

Tags: imap, mailkit

I'm really spent a lot of time searching about, but no luck.
My issue is not directly related to Mailkit working or not, it is doing right but perhaps someone here have a clue.
I have to look for mails unseen mails from specific mail address on a Exchange 2010 using IMAP. All work fine (until now) for any server except this one.

When "from" mail address in format like `John Doe <johndoe@pluto.com>` a search for `johndoe@pluto.com` does not return any UIDs;
`John Doe` return UID collection;

On the other hand if "from" mail is in plain format all works fine.

Does anybody have any idea or know if is it an issue on Exch2010?

As a work around I'm thinking to make a simple search unseen to get UIDs then Fetch and look at Envelope

By the way here I have on log when message from = `John Doe <johndoe@pluto.com>`;

```
C: A00000006 UID SEARCH CHARSET US-ASCII FROM johndoe@pluto.com
S: * SEARCH
S: A00000006 OK SEARCH completed.
```

Answer (score 2):

Almost 1 year later, seems I found why I can´t get any result when searching From when mail address have Display Name.

Here Dmitry explain Exchange behaviour
https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/dkhrebin/2013/10/04/how-exchange-imap-search-in-message-header/

A short quote say:

> If you use SEARCH FROM (for CC, BCC, TO idea the same) Exchange will search in message's Property: PR_SENT_REPRESENTING_NAME, PR_SENT_REPRESENTING_NAME_A,
>   ptagSentRepresentingName
>   The PR_SENT_REPRESENTING_NAME property contains the display name for the messaging user represented by the sender.

So in addition to:`SearchQuery.FromContains ("johndoe@pluto.com").Or (SearchQuery.FromContains ("John Doe"));`

I can use `SearchQuery.HeaderContains ("from", "johndoe@pluto.com");`

Since Display Name can be anything and can be changed anytime, and mail address is always same. I can deal with both commands command lines above.

But I can't determine which has the best performance.

Comment: In general, FROM will be faster than HEADER because most IMAP servers will cache the common header values for searching. Sounds like this might not be the case for Exchange, however.

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed that each IMAP server seems to behave differently with respect to searching for email addresses and/or Message-Id tokens.

What you may need to do is either do an OR search query:

```
SearchQuery.FromContains ("johndoe@pluto.com").Or (SearchQuery.FromContains ("John Doe"));
```

Perhaps that will work around the problem so it works with all IMAP servers?

Comment: By the way, I made some tests with Exchange and Outlook.Office365.
There is no problem searching on Outlook.Office365, does not matter if From have a Display Name, just search by real email address. (this was after my own answer in thread)

But on Exchange (at least 2010) if From have Display Name, you can get results only if search by Display Name.